# How to create table using loop and print variables in it | using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, loops, html-table

I am new in PHP. I want to create a table using loop and wants to print variables data in it fetching from Mysql. Here, I face some problems for creating table.

I want to create table like this:

[image]

But I failed in doing so.

My code is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <style>
      table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }

      table, td, th {
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
    </style>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>

  <?php
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "pacra1";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `letter_copy` WHERE `id` = 1";

    $conn->multi_query($sql);

    //$conn->next_result();

    $result = $conn->use_result();

    echo $conn->error; 
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    $opinion = $row['opinion'];
    $action = $row['action'];

    $opinion_chunks = explode(",", $opinion);

  ?>
  <div style="margin-top:auto; width:auto;font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; text-align:left; font-size:12px; text-align:center">
    <table width="657">
      <tr>
        <td width="225"> <strong>Opinion</strong></td>
        <td width="62"> <strong>Action</strong></td>
        <td colspan="4"><strong>Ratings</strong></td>
        <td width="54"><strong>Outlook</strong></td>
        <td width="67"><strong>Rating Type</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="225">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="62">&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2"><b>Long Term</b></td>
        <td colspan="2"><b>Short Term</b></td>
        <td width="54">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="67">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="225">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="62">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="52"><b>Current</b></td>
        <td width="45"><b>Previous</b></td>
        <td width="49"><b>Current</b></td>
        <td width="51"><b>Previous</b></td>
        <td width="54">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="67">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <?php

    echo '<table border="01">';
    foreach($opinion_chunks as $row){
      echo '<tr>';
      $row = explode(',',$row);
      $row1 = explode(",", $action);
      foreach($row as $cell){
        if ($cell == "")
          continue;
          echo '<td>';
          echo $cell;
          echo '</td>';
          foreach($row1 as $cell1){
            if ($cell1 == "")
              continue;
              echo '<td>';
              echo $cell1;
              echo '</td>';
          }
      }
      echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
  ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

And the output of my code is:

[image]

You can easily seen my problem.

Comment: can you provide the sql file, so it will become easy to help.

Comment: @Niranjan where i can put my file?

Comment: Don't provide the file. Edit your question content to include the code.

Comment: @Kuya Without db structure, how will we get to know the problem. Let his share 2 rows of data with table structure.

Comment: @Niranjan This is my db file link http://www.mediafire.com/view/3m0dym1aael8m81/letter_copy.sql

Comment: ok, i will check and will updae

Comment: @Niranjan m waiting for your response

Comment: you should break one row to 4 rows??

Comment: @Niranjan How i can?

Comment: check the code i have pasted in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did it by this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "pacra1";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM letter_copy WHERE id = 3"; 
  $conn->multi_query($sql); 
  //$conn->next_result(); 
  $result = $conn->use_result();

?>

<div style="margin-top:auto; width:auto;font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; text-align:left; font-size:12px">
<table width="657">
    <tr>
        <td width="225"> <strong>Opinion</strong></td>
        <td width="62"> <strong>Action</strong></td>
        <td colspan="4" style="text-align:center"><strong> Ratings</strong></td>
        <td width="54"><strong>Outlook</strong></td>
        <td width="67"><strong>Rating Type</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="225">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="62">&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2"><b>Long Term</b></td>
        <td colspan="2"><b>Short Term</b></td>
        <td width="54">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="67">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="225">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="62">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="52"><b>Current</b></td>
        <td width="45"><b>Previous</b></td>
        <td width="49"><b>Current</b></td>
        <td width="51"><b>Previous</b></td>
        <td width="54">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="67">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <?php foreach ($result as $row) { ?>

        <?php
        //$a = $row['action'];
        $action = explode(",", $row['action']);
        $long_term = explode(",", $row['long_term_rating']);
        $p_long_term = explode(",", $row['p_long_term_rating']);
        $short_term = explode(",", $row['short_term_rating']);
        $p_short_term = explode(",", $row['p_short_term_rating']);
        $outlook = explode(",", $row['outlook']);
        $opinion = explode(",", $row['opinion']);
        $rating_type = explode(",", $row['rating_type']);

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($opinion); $i++) {
            if ($opinion[$i] == "")continue;

            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= $opinion[$i] ?> </td>
                <td><?= $action[$i] ?> </td>
                <td><?= $long_term[$i] ?>  </td>
                <td><?= $p_long_term[$i] ?>  </td>
                <td><?= $short_term[$i] ?></td>
                <td><?= $p_short_term[$i] ?></td>
                <td><?= $outlook[$i] ?> </td>
                <td><?= $rating_type[$i]?></td>
            </tr>

        <?php }
    }
    ?>

</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want

```
    $q = "select * from letter_copy";
    $result = execute $q to get results



<div style="margin-top:auto; width:auto;font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; text-align:left; font-size:12px; text-align:center">
<table width="657" border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="225"> <strong>Opinion</strong></td>
        <td width="62"> <strong>Action</strong></td>
        <td colspan="4"><strong>Ratings</strong></td>
        <td width="54"><strong>Outlook</strong></td>
        <td width="67"><strong>Rating Type</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="225">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="62">&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2"><b>Long Term</b></td>
        <td colspan="2"><b>Short Term</b></td>
        <td width="54">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="67">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="225">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="62">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="52"><b>Current</b></td>
        <td width="45"><b>Previous</b></td>
        <td width="49"><b>Current</b></td>
        <td width="51"><b>Previous</b></td>
        <td width="54">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="67">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <?php foreach ($result as $row) { ?>

        <?php
        $action = explode(",", $row->action);
        $long_term = explode(",", $row->long_term_rating);

        $short_term = explode(",", $row->short_term_rating);
        $outlook = explode(",", $row->outlook);

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($action); $i++) {

            ?>
            <tr>

                <td><?= $row->opinion ?></td>
                <td><?= $action[$i] ?></td>

                <td><?= $long_term[$i] ?></td>
                <td><?= $long_term[$i] ?></td>
                <td><?= $short_term[$i] ?></td>
                <td><?= $short_term[$i] ?></td>
                <td><?= $outlook[$i] ?></td>
                <td><?= $row->rating_type_title ?></td>
            </tr>

        <?php }
    }
    ?>

</table>
```

Comment: it show error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$q' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyFirstWebsite\letter\explode.php on line 30`

Comment: enclode first 2 lines inside php tags

Comment: it show error on `$q = "select * from letter_copy";
    $result = execute $q to get results`

Comment: in $result write your code to fetct the data from db

Comment: i have written text there `execute $q to get results`

Comment: you should execute the mysql query there.

Comment: Im not that familiar with core php

Comment: How I can do it? Please tell me

Comment: <?php
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "pacra1";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `letter_copy` WHERE `id` = 1";

    $conn->multi_query($sql);

    //$conn->next_result();

    $result = $conn->use_result();
?P>O

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88663/discussion-between-niranjan-and-sunny).